# Teamcity 9 - passing arguments between build and deploy projects

Tags: teamcity-9.0

i have teamcity 9 with build and deploy functions and they are set that the deploy depends on the build.
i want to switch those because i'm trying to work with the REST API of teamcity to call for builds from remote.

my problem is that when i'm calling the deploy with arguments it isnt passing them to the build.

i have placed major/minor System Properties in the deploy and so when i call it from remote it gets the values but its not passing it to the build.

can anyone let me know if this is possible and if so what are the arguments that i need to set in the build in order to get the values from the deploy.

thanks,

Comment: I assume you have a project and there you have two build configuraitons right? One for build and the other one for deployment? Where did you define the parameter?

Comment: Yes - that is what i have.
The parameters are defined in the build.

i want to change that so that the deploy will hold the params and through the HTTP call will move it to the build to build the correct version.